# Formula not working

Tags: excel

```
=IF(F5=0,[E5-E5*$H$1],[F5-F5*$H$1])
```

I have two columns of data that can be used and I want the calculation to take data from the first column only when the second column is blank (I didn't know how to add blank in so have opted for `=0`) and then perform the calculation referring to a fixed reference cell.

So if `F5` is blank then take `EF` into the calculation referring to `H1` as the fixed reference (`5%` is in `H1`).  Information in columns `E`&`F` are manually input prices, `E` column is normal retail price and a figure only appears in `F` column if the item is selling at a reduced price.

I want one calculation in column `G` that takes the most current price and works out `-5%`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.
For cell say, G5:
`=IF(F5,F5-(F5*$H$1),E5-(E5*$H$1))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For cell <kbd>G5</kbd>:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F5);E5;F5)*(1-$H$1)
```